# Cannot Play Youtube video in video View

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

am trying to play youtube video  into android videoView but its shows a dialog box cannot play video using android 4.4 and higher versions i got some example but its using intent.my requirement is to play youtube video into my app layout

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private VideoView videoView;
    private MediaController mController;
    private Uri uriYouTube;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        mController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mController);
        videoView.requestFocus();

 /*Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/"
 + R.raw.sample);
 videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
 videoView.start();*/

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int loc = savedInstanceState.getInt("Loc");
            Log.i("Loaction: ", loc + "");
            uriYouTube = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("url"));
            videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
            videoView.seekTo(loc);
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.v("onPrepared", "ok");
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        } else {
            RTSPUrlTask truitonTask = new RTSPUrlTask();
            truitonTask.execute("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zNSgSzhBfM");
        }

    }

    void startPlaying(String url) {
        uriYouTube = Uri.parse(url);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uriYouTube);
        videoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("Loc", videoView.getCurrentPosition());
        outState.putString("url", uriYouTube.toString());
    }

   /* @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video_view, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

    private class RTSPUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = getRTSPVideoUrl(urls[0]);
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            startPlaying(result);
        }

        public String getRTSPVideoUrl(String urlYoutube) {
            try {
                String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                        .newDocumentBuilder();
                String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
                URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
                Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
                String cursor = urlYoutube;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = list.item(i);
                    if (node != null) {
                        NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                        HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++) {
                            Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                            maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                        }
                        if (maps.containsKey("yt:format")) {
                            String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                            if (maps.containsKey("url"))
                                cursor = maps.get("url");
                            if (f.equals("1"))
                                return cursor;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cursor;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return urlYoutube;
            }
        }

        public String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
            String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
            String[] param = query.split("&");
            String id = null;
            for (String row : param) {
                String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                if (param1[0].equals("v")) {
                    id = param1[1];
                }
            }
            return id;
        }
    }
    }
```

[image]

can u please give me a solution.

Error Log

```
E/MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException! uri=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zNSgSzhBfM
               java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zNSgSzhBfM
                   at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1123)
                   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:958)
                   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:881)
                   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1018)
                   at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:437)
                   at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:342)
                   at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:325)
                   at com.ulguru.lms.testyoutube.YoutubeActivity.startPlaying(YoutubeActivity.java:68)
                   at com.ulguru.lms.testyoutube.YoutubeActivity$RTSPUrlTask.onPostExecute(YoutubeActivity.java:95)
                   at com.ulguru.lms.testyoutube.YoutubeActivity$RTSPUrlTask.onPostExecute(YoutubeActivity.java:85)
                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

Comment: You can use YouTube APIs , have a look on this project - https://github.com/xibsked/Android-MVP

Comment: i need to play video in my video view